# C how to pass pointer to struct array pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I realize this is most likely a syntax issue, however, I have a struct:

```
struct pixel{
int pixel_num;
double lowest_dist;
int centroid;
double * location;
};
```

and an array of these structs `struct pixel * pixel_data[10]` 
and a method: `void foo(double ** arr)` and am trying to pass the address of the `location` pointer in an instance of the struct to update the pointer in the method `foo`.

I attempted to pass it like so `foo(&(pixel_data[0]->location))` however this is clearly not correct as when I run through gdb the `*arr` values are different in `foo` than what they were in `main()` where I call foo.

Thanks.

An Example:

```
#define DIMENSIONS 5
//Struct is declared in header.
//max 10 pixels
struct pixel * pixel_data[10];

int main(){
    double newLoc[DIMENSIONS]={1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4, 5.5};
    pixel_data[0]=add_pixel(newLoc);
    update_centroid_location(&(pixel_data[0]->location), 0, DIMENSIONS);
}
void update_centroid_location(double **centroid, int centroid_num, int numpix){
    double * old_cent=malloc(DIMENSIONS*sizeof(double));
    if(!old_cent){
    perror("couldnt allocate memory");
    exit(4);
    }   
    for(int i=0;i<DIMENSIONS;i++){
    old_cent[i]=*centroid[i]; //segfaults here as cannot access memory address
    }   
}
struct pixel * add_pixel(double * location){
    struct pixel * new=malloc(sizeof(struct pixel));
    if(!new){
    perror("Could not allocate space for pixel");
    exit(4);
    }   
    new->lowest_dist=DBL_MAX;
    new->centroid=0;
    new->location=location;
    return new;
}
```

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] - I find it hard to understand what the problem is with the function call

Comment: You do know that ```struct pixel * pixel_data[10]``` is an array of 10 invalid pointers and needs initialization, do not you? And that is just one aspect which could go wrong, that is why seeing some more code would be nice.

Comment: `int i-0` is not valid. Also that code is still not complete in many other ways. Create something that compiles **and** shows your problem.

Comment: ```printf("%c", location[i]);``` is a bit hard to interpret, given that it is the first occurrence of ```location``` and generally there are no traces of char variables (for ```%c```) in your code and/or description.

Comment: The example above should be more helpful. Apologies. @UnholySheep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line `old_cent[i]=*centroid[i];` there is a misunderstanding about [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).
The `*` operator has a lower precedence than the `[]`.
So you are essentially doing `old_cent[i]=*(centroid[i]);`

Try to use parenthesis to explicitly express that you want to first dereference then add the offset for the second dereference like so:

```
old_cent[i]=(*centroid)[i];
```